# Adding multiple background images and background colors to css

Tags: css, image, background

So im trying to add two background images within the body of my css however when I do it doesn't execute both images only the first image. I then tried to execute two background colors but again didn't execute. Is there anyway I can fix this?

body{

Background-image:
url("https://garden.spoonflower.com/c/6352249/p/f/l/jwkc2F7Ud3R3T9PlYkBODNtUwLKbyglqcoyRW3raDn-TUIAtnl0/Dark%20Mulberry%2C%20Solid%20Colour.jpg"), url("https://garden.spoonflower.com/c/4277276/p/f/m/FbshAkngoexiw8kWbTJQ1FN8mihBoks9G3hV09i7nbwB9RzM0gQY_LD8/solid%20pale%20pastel%20purple%20(EEE0FF).jpg");

}

I tried to put both images however it didn't show both

Answer (score 1):

```css
    body {
    Background-image: url("https://garden.spoonflower.com/c/6352249/p/f/l/jwkc2F7Ud3R3T9PlYkBODNtUwLKbyglqcoyRW3raDn-TUIAtnl0/Dark%20Mulberry%2C%20Solid%20Colour.jpg"), url("https://garden.spoonflower.com/c/4277276/p/f/m/FbshAkngoexiw8kWbTJQ1FN8mihBoks9G3hV09i7nbwB9RzM0gQY_LD8/solid%20pale%20pastel%20purple%20(EEE0FF).jpg");
    background-position: right bottom, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Text</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent one image from covering another you can change background-size:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://garden.spoonflower.com/c/6352249/p/f/l/jwkc2F7Ud3R3T9PlYkBODNtUwLKbyglqcoyRW3raDn-TUIAtnl0/Dark%20Mulberry%2C%20Solid%20Colour.jpg"), 
                url("https://garden.spoonflower.com/c/4277276/p/f/m/FbshAkngoexiw8kWbTJQ1FN8mihBoks9G3hV09i7nbwB9RzM0gQY_LD8/solid%20pale%20pastel%20purple%20(EEE0FF).jpg");
  background-position:50% 50% ,50%;
background-size: 50% 75%, cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:100vh
}
```

Comment: Thank you this really helped me out. Question if i wanted to slightly lower the first image what would i add to lower it?

Comment: Manipulate `background-postion` and `background-size` then, they have values for 1st & 2nd background separated by comma `,` . You can use any unit you want, or predefined keywords like :`cover`,`contain` etc.  I edited the asnwer.

Comment: Thank you i deeply appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `background-position` and `background-size` to position and resize you backgrounds as you want:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://garden.spoonflower.com/c/6352249/p/f/l/jwkc2F7Ud3R3T9PlYkBODNtUwLKbyglqcoyRW3raDn-TUIAtnl0/Dark%20Mulberry%2C%20Solid%20Colour.jpg"), 
                    url("https://garden.spoonflower.com/c/4277276/p/f/m/FbshAkngoexiw8kWbTJQ1FN8mihBoks9G3hV09i7nbwB9RzM0gQY_LD8/solid%20pale%20pastel%20purple%20(EEE0FF).jpg");
  background-position: left, right;
  background-size: 50%, 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```